# It is possible to connect a device to a router using WDS Bridging via lan cable , and get internet through it?

Tags: networking, router, wds

First of all, sorry but im kind of a noob in networking and i dont know the offical terminology, that being said, let me explain you my issue:
I have a router in a room, which delivers internet through ethernet cables and wifi to various pc's, i also have an old router which im using as a wifi extender via wds bridging, because i dont have space to put another eth cable, however i have a device which cannot connect to the network via wifi, and needs to use an ethernet cable.
Now here comes the question, is it possible to connect the device to the old router via an eth cable and connect to internet through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a WDS link can carry traffic bridged from either wired or wireless devices, at either end of the link. In fact, one of the main uses WDS was designed for was for wirelessly bridging the Ethernet LANs of two nearby buildings.

Comment: Just make sure that the wired device is connected to that router on one of the LAN ports, not the WAN port.